# Header background not tall enough with the new top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With the top bar redesign (currently mod-only, broader rollout [planned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network) for the next couple of weeks) in Chrome the header seems not to be tall enough to contain its content anymore. In this image, you can see the blue translucent background under "QUESTIONS" overhanging the background pattern on the bottom, and under the "PHYSICS" logo, part of that image also overhangs the background.

[image: screenshot of site header]

I've tested this on a few browsers and found that it occurs with Chrome 60.0.3112.113 on OS X and Chromium 59.0.3071.104 on Linux, but not with Firefox 52.3.0 on Linux, Vivaldi 1.11.917.43 on Linux, or Safari 10.1.2 (12603.3.8) on OS X. So, seemingly Chrome-specific.

Can this be checked and fixed?

Comment: I don't have that on my end.  It's all lined up.  I'm on chrome (not sure what version).

Comment: Huh. I'll add browser information; maybe it's browser-specific.

Comment: thanks for reporting. i'll take a look.

Comment: -1, cannot reproduce :-P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks again for reporting. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep, looks good on Linux, and I will verify on the Mac tomorrow.